# How to edit .sln file in TFS 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

I need to delete several lines from the solution file (.sln). When changing .csproj files I can use "Unload project". But what is the proper way to edit .sln file in TFS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your best bet is to close the solution and use a text editor (Notepad or equivalent) instead.

Comment: This was the first thing I did but TFS didn't recognize any changes.

Comment: You'd need to check out the solution file manually before editing, and then check in afterwards.

Comment: Yes, I didn't Checkout for Edit. Thx. Procedure: In Source Control Explorer 1) Checkout for Edit; 2) Change in Notepad; 3) Checkin; 4) File Modification Detected -> Reload.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the TFS Powertools for that purpose. It enables you to make tfs-"operations" from the windows explorer (and edit the .sln file with an txteditor).

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to copy the sln in Visual Studio as a temporary text file, and edit there. I used this to handle some changes like regex updates to the sln file, without having to use the VS UI to adjust tons of build processor changes (and without having to do it using a public online web tool).
Once the text was updated, paste the new text back into the original sln file and save, using a tool like notepad, etc. VS will then tell you it needs to reload the new sln, and the changes will be loaded.